# Как настроить clion для работы с windows

Tags: c++, windows, clion

Возникла потребность работы из под windows, до этого работал исключительно из под linux. Установил clion, указал путь к компилятору, но, несмотря на то что указанный путь существует, clion его не видит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там не надо указывать путь к компилятору, там надо установить environment, если clion ее поддерживает, то все остальные поля будут заполнены автоматически.

Comment: @user7860670, что нужно установить для компилятора MinGW

Comment: у них на сайте есть инструкция на эту тему https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#Cygwin - похоже там  нужно обязательно установить make и gdb